# Make a ROS node that does spatial median filtering on the "msg.ranges"

Tags: python, arrays, filter, ros

**I hope to write a median filter with a window width of 3, that is, three [1,2,3,4,5,6] output as [1,3,4,6]. So, I tried to write the following node. But, As a rookie, I still don't know how to convert python code into ROS node to work. So, can you help me write this node?**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
"""

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan

def las_callback(msg):

#function definition pass two angument
 def medfiter(X,win_len):


#this function return shape and type of x
  Y=np.zeros_like(X)


#initualize value of padwidth
  padwidth=int((win_len-1)/2)

#pading array X
  X=np.pad(X,((0,0),(padwidth,padwidth)))

#loop in i read from padwidth value to the X.shape[1]-padwidth
for i in range(padwidth,X.shape[1]-padwidth):

#store median in y variable of x variable by passing columns and rows of data in median function

  Y[:,i-padwidth]=np.median(X[:,i-padwidth:i+padwidth+1],axis=1)

#return variable y
return Y
 
     
rospy.init_node('laser_readings')
sub = rospy.Subscriber('/base_scan', LaserScan, las_callback)
rospy.spin()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should, first check which message type you have as a data format. In your case you have LaserScan. Here you can see the data structure for [LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html)

So you must be interested in ranges (float list) to apply median filter. So get the data as

```
data = msg.ranges
```

now you have a list(data), ready for your operation.